# Build successful but UWP application crashes when rendering landing component for React Native Windows Build

Tags: react-native, windowsbuilder

I am having a problem with a UWP app that is crashing on startup. It crashes only once after the app is installed, either via Debug button on VS2022 or via the CMD "npm run windows"

```
Developer Mode is turned ON in Windows Settings App.
Windows system version:
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H2
Install the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 with the following options checked:
Workloads
Node.js development, or one of the following alternatives:
Install from Individual Components:
Development activities
Node.js development support
Install Node.js separately, see below for some options
.NET Desktop development
Desktop development with C++
Include MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest) (check under 'Optional')
Universal Windows Platform development
Include C++ (v143) Universal Windows Platform tools (check under 'Optional') missing in community version of VS 2022
Individual Components
Include Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0) (target OS version from this table)
Include MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ ARM64 build tools (Latest) (to target ARM64 devices)
Enable Long Paths in Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later.
Install the latest version of the .NET 6.0 SDK.
```

After installing all dependencies we found the following error

I am trying to build this application from cmd and visual studio 2022

Could you please give us suggestion to fixed this issue.

Comment: Please add error messages and other debug information.